# How to produce a green check mark on the menu tabs by using before and after selectors in css ?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list of menu tabs aligned vertically. The pictorial representation of it is: [image]

My task is to make a green check mark next to every menu tabs in the following way(as shown in the below image):

[image: ActualMenuTabs]

I am trying to make it by using the following CSS code but unfortunately the check mark is getting displayed before the title (Personal Information or Smoking Status or Employment Information or Direct Deposit) as shown below:

[image: Tick Mark before title].

The CSS code which I have used for all the menu tabs is:

```
  div.default.tabs ul.child:first-child li.child.active::after 
  {   
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10.5px;
  content: "✔";
  font-size:xx-large;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#9CD106;
  font-weight: normal;
  }
```

Comment: change `left:20px` to `right:20px` ?

Comment: can you show us your mark up

Comment: Yes, it works by changing it from left to right. Actually there was a problem in the parent class which was preventing me to do so.

Comment: what is preventing you to do that hmm are all the `li` tags positioned relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `left:20px;` to `right:20px;` if you just want to align the check on the right side